# Error getting route from urls.py

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm testing the application. It is necessary to test the method of processing requests coming to the address 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/test/api_address/'. Tell me, please, as through reverse () the full address to the client

```
class MyTestCase(APITestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.message = {
            'username': 'user_name',
            'password': 'user_password',
        }

    def test_get_token(self):
        response = self.client.post(reverse('api_address'), self.message)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Code for `urls.py`:

```
users_router = DefaultRouter()
users_router.register(r'test', TestViewSet, 'test')
users_router.register(r'test/api_address', APIAddressRequestSet, 'api_address')
```

with the current implementation, reverse ('map address') does not work, falling with an error:

```
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'api_address' not found. 'api_address' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

Comment: If you get an error, you should post the whole thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The url names for `DefaultRouter` are automatically generated, check [the docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/).

Set a `base_name` first:

```
# urls.py    
users_router = DefaultRouter()
users_router.register(r'test', TestViewSet, base_name='test')
users_router.register(r'test/api_address', APIAddressRequestSet,
                      base_name='api_address')
```

Now your urls are reverse-accessible via `reverse('test-list')` `reverse('test-detail')`, etc. Check the table in the docs for the other names.

Your updated test:

```
class MyTestCase(APITestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.message = {
            'username': 'user_name',
            'password': 'user_password',
        }

    def test_get_token(self):
        # note the appended `-list` to the url name
        response = self.client.post(reverse('api_address-list'), self.message)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not help: `django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'api_address' not found. 'api_address' is not a valid view function or pattern name.`

Comment: Please read [the docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/). The `DefaultRouter` will append `-list` and `-detail` to your url name. I updated my answer with your tests.